# Fully remove the non-unique values

Tags: powershell, csv

I have an input CSV with a column similar to the below

```
1334
1334
3556
3556
3558
4897
4897
5978
6001
6001
```

Unlike a *unique* modifier for sort, I'm attempting to completely remove all the duplicates, so the only values that remain are ones that only appear one time, like the below

```
3558
5978
```

Comment: use `Group-Object` and toss out the ones with `.Count` greater than `1`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one-liner for what @Lee_Dailey suggested:

```
Get-Content -Path $PathToCSV | Group-Object | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Count -eq 1 } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```